# Finding the depth of a particular node in a tree using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently trying to solve a problem where I return the maximum depth a number appears in a tree. For example, if a tree looks like this:

```
    1
  /   \
2      3
        \
         2
```

My function should return 2. Yet, my function returns 0

```
def max_depth(t,value):
    if t == None:
        return -1
    left = max_depth(t.left, value)
    right = max_depth(t.right, value)
    if t.value == value:
        return 1 + max(left,right)
    else:
        return max(left,right)
```

Is my thought process wrong? I should add `1` if the current value matches the one I'm looking for (which is the parameter), and do not add `1` if they do not match.  I use `max()` so it returns the maximum of either the left child or the right child, so I get the child with the higher depth. Is that wrong?

Here is the tree class:

```
class TN:
    def __init__(self,value,left=None,right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right
```

And here is my construction of the tree:

```
tree4 = TN(2)
tree3 = TN(3, left = None, right = tree4)
tree2 = TN(2)
tree1 = TN(1, left = tree2, right = tree3)
print(max_depth(tree1, 2))
```

That will print `0`

Comment: can you post the full code that produces error?

Comment: @AliYılmaz What do you mean? The function I have above is all of the code I have

Comment: I meant the tree class you use, and the tree instance you call  `max_depth` upon. I would like to help but I cant find enough code here to test it myself.

Comment: @AliYılmaz Edited the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem you're trying to solve is: **what's the maximum depth of the value `value` in the tree.**

You should increase the count **not only** when `t.value == value`, but also when any of the descendants of the tree matches the value you're looking for. This is because you're measuring the depth.

Here's how the algorithm should look like:

```
def max_depth(t,value):
    if t == None:
        return -1
    left = max_depth(t.left, value)
    right = max_depth(t.right, value)
    if t.value == value or left > -1 or right > -1: # <<<<
        return 1 + max(left,right)
    else:
        return max(left,right) # This is always -1
```

Comment: correct! also, there is no need to compute `else: return max(left, right)`. Because that else statement means there is no value matched in either left or right subtrees.

Comment: @AliYılmaz: Right. the value in the `else` part is always `-1`

Comment: @Aziz Upon some thought I have a question about why my solution doesn't work. You said I should increase the count also when the descendants match the value I'm looking for. With the recursive call going back to if t.value == value, isn't that what I'm doing? In my original code I have if t.value == value then add all my results together after getting the maximum. Shouldn't that add all the results from children trees?

Comment: @Tyler: Let's look at the example tree you provided. The right branch has: 1, 3, 2. At the leaf node (2), you will add `1` because `t.value==value`. However, this `1` will go back to the the parent node (3), and it won't add `1` to it ... It will just return it as is. Hence, you're not really measuring depth. Same goes for the root of the tree (1).

Comment: @Aziz Oh I see now. So it returns 1 and gets lost, not saved, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a nice encoding of `max_depth`

We add an additional parameter `d` with a default value of `0`. This parameter is used to keep track of the current depth. When returning an answer, we only include `d` in the `max (d, ...)` when the node `t` value matches – otherwise, we return the max of the `left` and `right` results

```
def max_depth (t, value, d = 0):
  if t is None:
    return -1
  elif t.value == value:
    return max ( d
               , max_depth (t.left, value, d + 1)
               , max_depth (t.right, value, d + 1)
               )
  else:
    return max ( max_depth (t.left, value, d + 1)
               , max_depth (t.right, value, d + 1)
               )
```

Here's the tree from the code in your question

```
tree = \
  TN (1, TN (2), TN (3, right = TN (2)))
```

Find the max depth of each value

```
print (max_depth (tree, 1))
# 0

print (max_depth (tree, 2))
# 2

print (max_depth (tree, 3))
# 1
```

In the event the value is never found, `-1` will be returned

```
print (max_depth (tree, 4))
# -1
```